# Color Column Headers using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a excel file which was generated using python. I am just trying to clean it up a little using python.

- **Remove** the 'Unnamed:' header, although I want to keep the row# under it.
- **Add** a highlight for the column header starting with the **title** of the appended **df** and the **mean** and **max** **column headers**

**Here is a before and after**

[image: BEFORE]

vs

[image: AFTER]

Comment: using pandas presumably? Since it's unsaid.

Comment: as I know pandas may not have function to set colors, etc. and it may need modules created specially for `excel` files - i.e. [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: What's the argument against [Styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)?

Comment: I have tried with pandas, but it is not working with the df.style approach

Comment: I got this error                                                                                                                  
       def color_fill(val):
    if "max" in val:
        styling = 'background-color: red; color:black'
    return styling 

df = df.style.applymap(color_fill)         @creanion

Comment: error: AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'     I have googl;ed this but none of the fixes seem to work @Vitalizzare

Comment: Instead of converting it to a df should i rather just add excel files using xlsxwriter 
 @furas

Comment: What does the do say about using pandas styler and excel? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel

Comment: I'm not sure but it may use styles when it generate HTML with table. I don't know if it can use it when it save excel. `pandas` was created to work with table which it can read from excel, csv, database, etc. so it is not specialized for excel. Modules like `xlsxwriter` or `openpyxl` are created to work with excel and they may have special for setting colors in excel. [openpyxl - styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)